# Fluid is flowing from nozzle in upward direction

Tags: fluid-mechanics

If a nozzle is projected upwards with water flowing with a certain flow rate
then in how many ways can you find the diameter of the jet of water at a certain 
height from the nozzle exit?

One approach- We can find velocity at that height and we know the discharge so we can find diameter from here
Do you have some other approach

Comment: Show some effort towards a solution, as otherwise people feel you are treating us as a free homework solution provider.

Comment: One approach- We can find velocity at that height and we know the discharge so we can find diameter from here
Do you have some other approach

Comment: Based on your idea, at some point along the jet, the velocity will be zero which gives area tending to infinity. So try to include some more complication to the problem. Hint : Can you model this flow as u = f(x,y) & v =f(x,y,g)? where g is gravitational acceleration. This kind flow called as stagnation point flow.